# How to handle PHP-Array with multiple & one item

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an JSON from an API which is converted into an PHP-Array with `json_decode()`.

Array with one item:

```
    Array
    (
        [commentID] => 11
        [authorIDFK] => 1
        [comment] => Nice
    )
```

Array with multiple itmes:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [commentID] => 11
                [authorIDFK] => 1
                [comment] => Nice
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [commentID] => 15
                [authorIDFK] => 2
                [comment] => Great
            )

    )
```

To process the array I have something like

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
   echo $comment['comment'];
}
```

But if the array only has one item, it fails to process. Any ideas how to achieve this? If I use `count()` on the 1-item-array it counts 3 entries.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Please see the updated answer, I had conditions reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test the presence of `$comments[0]` (using [`isset()`](https://php.net/isset)), if not, wrap the array into another array. So, you will ever get the same format:

```
$comments = ['commentID' => 11, 'authorIDFK' => 1, 'comment' => 'Nice'];

if (!isset($comments[0])) $comments=[$comments];

foreach($comments as $comment) {
   echo $comment['comment'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a function like this:

```
function isAssoc(array $arr)
{
    if (array() === $arr) return false;
    return array_keys($arr) !== range(0, count($arr) - 1);
}
```

Now when When you get the data,

```
if ($this->isAssoc($data)) {
    // single assoc array
    echo $data['comment'];
}
else {
   // indexed array
   foreach($data as $comment{
       echo $comment['comment'];
    }
}
```